# Scrapy interpreting html entities on extract

Tags: python, scrapy

During a crawling, I captured links usually that way:

```
response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, something)/@href").extract()
```

But for some reason in that specific page was not working. What I was receiving in the array was something like this:

```
['details?lm==true=1=A43', (...)]
```

The correct output should be:

```
['details?lm=&printerView=true&accessType=1&id=A43', (...)]
```

Answer (score 1):

After sometime, I discovered that the same page on firefox was rendering weird... My problem has been happening because the page being crawled was with the content-type as "text/xml" and not html.

To fix my code I did other selector:

```
sel = scrapy.Selector(text=response.body)
sel.xpath("//a[contains(@class, something)/@href").extract()
```

And now I have the correct result!

```
['details?lm=&printerView=true&accessType=1&id=A43', (...)]
```