# Extract specific value from HTML using xpath and scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I have following html Code:

```html
<tr data-live="COumykPG" data-dt="10,11,2017,19,00" data-def="1">
<td class="table-matches__tt"><span class="table-matches__time" data-live-cell="time">19:00</span><a href="/soccer/germany/oberliga-bremen/oberneuland-habenhauser/COumykPG/" data-live-cell="matchlink"><span>Oberneuland</span> - <span>Habenhauser</span></a></td>
<td class="livebet" data-live-cell="livebet">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="table-matches__streams" data-live-cell="score">
</td>
<td class="table-matches__odds" data-oid="2p2k5xv464x0x6ev9v"><a href="/myselections.php?action=3&amp;matchid=COumykPG&amp;outcomeid=2p2k5xv464x0x6ev9v&amp;otheroutcomes=2p2k5xv498x0x0,2p2k5xv464x0x6eva0" onclick="return my_selections_click('1x2', 'soccer');" title="Add to My Selections" target="mySelections">1.10</a></td>
<td class="table-matches__odds" data-oid="2p2k5xv498x0x0"><a href="/myselections.php?action=3&amp;matchid=COumykPG&amp;outcomeid=2p2k5xv498x0x0&amp;otheroutcomes=2p2k5xv464x0x6ev9v,2p2k5xv464x0x6eva0" onclick="return my_selections_click('1x2', 'soccer');" title="Add to My Selections" target="mySelections">7.44</a></td>
<td class="table-matches__odds" data-oid="2p2k5xv464x0x6eva0"><a href="/myselections.php?action=3&amp;matchid=COumykPG&amp;outcomeid=2p2k5xv464x0x6eva0&amp;otheroutcomes=2p2k5xv464x0x6ev9v,2p2k5xv498x0x0" onclick="return my_selections_click('1x2', 'soccer');" title="Add to My Selections" target="mySelections">12.40</a></td>
</tr>
```

I try to scrap from the following code the 3 float values: `1,10`  `7.44`   `12.40`
The expression that i tried to use for geting the value was the following:

```
response.xpath('//a/@target').extract()
```

Output that I get is `'mySelections'`.

Iwant to get the value next to it. What is the right expression for it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

### What's wrong

response.xpath('//a/**@target**').extract()

### Why?

- If you format your HTML, the error is obvious.

  > You want to extract `text` from `a` tag, not the `target` attribute.

  ```
          <tr data-live="COumykPG" data-dt="10,11,2017,19,00" data-def="1">
             <td class="table-matches__tt">
                <span class="table-matches__time" data-live-cell="time">19:00</span>
                <a href="/soccer/germany/oberliga-bremen/oberneuland-habenhauser/COumykPG/" data-live-cell="matchlink">
                <span>Oberneuland</span> - <span>Habenhauser</span>
                </a>
             </td>
             <td class="livebet" data-live-cell="livebet">&nbsp;</td>
             <td class="table-matches__streams" data-live-cell="score"></td>
             <td class="table-matches__odds" data-oid="2p2k5xv464x0x6ev9v">

             <a href="/myselections.php?action=3&amp;matchid=COumykPG&amp;outcomeid=2p2k5xv464x0x6ev9v&amp;otheroutcomes=2p2k5xv498x0x0,2p2k5xv464x0x6eva0" 
                onclick="return my_selections_click('1x2', 'soccer');" 
                title="Add to My Selections" 
                target="mySelections">1.10</a>

             </td>
             <td class="table-matches__odds" data-oid="2p2k5xv498x0x0">

             <a href="/myselections.php?action=3&amp;matchid=COumykPG&amp;outcomeid=2p2k5xv498x0x0&amp;otheroutcomes=2p2k5xv464x0x6ev9v,2p2k5xv464x0x6eva0" 
                onclick="return my_selections_click('1x2', 'soccer');" 
                title="Add to My Selections" 
                target="mySelections">7.44</a>

             </td>
             <td class="table-matches__odds" data-oid="2p2k5xv464x0x6eva0">

             <a href="/myselections.php?action=3&amp;matchid=COumykPG&amp;outcomeid=2p2k5xv464x0x6eva0&amp;otheroutcomes=2p2k5xv464x0x6ev9v,2p2k5xv498x0x0" 
                onclick="return my_selections_click('1x2', 'soccer');" 
                title="Add to My Selections" 
                target="mySelections">12.40</a>

             </td>
          </tr>
  ```

  ## How to fix it
- Use one of those followings

  - `response.xpath('//a/text()').extract()`
  - According to other developers, `response.xpath` sometimes will cause bugs, you should use `scrapy's selector` instead.

    ```
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    result_array = Selector(text=response.body).xpath('//a/text()').extract()
    ```

Comment: scrapy's xpath uses that selector, do you have an example of such bugs?

Comment: Please take a look at: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206593/scrapy-interpreting-html-entities-on-extract)

Comment: I see, probably it would have worked with the correct content-type